# Customizing / extending move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, pluginlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I want to customize or modify the implementation of `move_base`. For example, I might want to add functionality, such that the one described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/229221) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/28950), or simply tweak the logic of its [internal state machine](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Expected_Robot_Behavior) a bit. Let's assume these changes will not end up in a pull request and merged upstream, which gives us more wiggle room. Let's also assume that I want to have access to the original version of `move_base`.

What would be an elegant way of adding such functionality? Here are some thoughts:

- "Fork" `move_base` (i.e., copy its source code), rename everything to `custom_move_base` or something, and implement the desired functionality / extensions in this new package. This would make it hard to maintain though. An example of this is [hector_move_base_navigation](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_move_base_navigation)
- Implement a new class that inherits from `move_base`. This would avoid duplicating simple functions, such as `isQuaternionValid`, but would allow for overriding the key functionality, such as `executeCycle`. I have a hunch that this will be more complicated than it sounds.
- If the extensions / modifications were focused on a specific aspect of `move_base`, e.g. the state machine logic, then maybe it would make sense to introduce, e.g., "state machine plugins" which would make the internal behavior of `move_base` configurable. Then the current logic would just be one of many possible options.

Looking forward to your thoughts :-)

PS. Now that we have [Discourse](http://discourse.ros.org/), would this question be a better fit for that as opposed to ROS Answers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229869/customizing-/-extending-move_base/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done some work on this front, enabling [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8_5SJDLAtg)

The work is [in this branch](https://github.com/DLu/navigation/compare/groovy_dev...DLu:groovy_mbsplit), although it breaks a number of existing binaries, so I never worked on merging it. What I should do is something similar to option 1 to enable option 3.

P.S. From the announcement:

> answers.ros.org remains your resource
> for asking specific technical
> questions about ROS, while Discourse
> should be used for more open-ended
> discussion and community organization.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-22**:
Very cool. Thanks David. That branch of yours has other useful functionality too, such as the [additional MoveBase action feedback](https://github.com/DLu/navigation/blob/a5a0827ea98c663c7c21f989c55147f2a00717f4/move_base_msgs/action/MoveBase.action) :-)

Thanks for answering the meta-question too.